# firebase + facebook front end - Front end query

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase

I am trying to do a facebook login for my firebase app. This is the first time I am using a FB login. I went through the article and small tutorials. But I am stuck at the front end

i.e the button creating part in my index.html and linking it to my firebase variable.

I saw the firefeed example and it is very differently done from the procedure on the FB developers guide. Any help will be great.

As an extension to the login I also want to access the graph data of the user logging in

This is my javascript, What will go in my HTML.

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('[myFirebase]');

var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(myDataRef);

authClient.login("facebook", function (err, token, info) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Got token " + token + " for user " + info.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: It would probably help a great deal to know what you tried and what went wrong. Did you try printing `err` in your example above? Did it have anything to say?

Comment: I am unable to figure out how get that F login button and then how to bind the button to the login variable

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://firebase.github.io/firebase-simple-login/ for an example of Firebase Simple Login in action that you can copy / fork and drop into your application.

Here's a simple example of an application which allows you to login to Facebook upon link click:

Login

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase("[myFirebase]");
    var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(firebaseRef, function(error, user) {
      if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log('an error occurred:');
        console.log(error);
      } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log('logged in:');
        console.log(user);
      } else {
        // user is logged out
        console.log('logged out');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: super got it up and running." scope: 'email,user_likes'" how do I access the user likes. is it accessible through auth variable?

Comment: I tried implementing the steps for the graph api along with the above implementation. It shows some duplicate not allowed error on the FB front, this does mean that firebase has already imported the necessary stuff. Am i right?

Comment: Firebase authenticates the user with Facebook, and gives you access to the Facebook access token via the user.accessToken variable. That token can then be used to make API requests to the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Comment: @RobDiMarco I have no idea how to use singly with firebase even after reading singly doc. So I would use your method. Do you mean we can call facebook graph api like this?
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` and get the return data?   But how to get the return data in JS ?

Comment: I think i got it. use $http in angularjs