# Angularfire/Firebase Facebook Authentication - A Better Profile Picture

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase, angularfire

I am hoping someone can help me find a way to get a higher resolution profile picture from my Facebook Authentication using Firebase & Angularfire.

Right now everything is working as it should. I am passing the following permissions to Firebase: `"public_profile, user_friends, email"` since they do not require a Facebook review. My app is still in development and is not ready for that part yet.

What I have done:

1. Extensively researched this specifically with Firebase, and have not had any luck.
2. All resources I do find here or elsewhere deal with calling graph.facebook.com directly, something I can't do with Firebase.

The `public_profile` permission does give me a secured image, but set 100x100px (https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p100x100...)

I am also facing the same issue with Twitter, but I will deffer that. Google gives you a great image.

I am using the latest stable releases.

Does anyone know of a way to get a better quality picture in a Angular/Firebase situation? I am open to any suggestions/workarounds.

If it helps, here is some code from my authentication service:

```js
function socialLogin(provider, options) {
  // prefer pop-ups, so we don't navigate away from the page
  return fbAuth.$authWithOAuthPopup(provider, options).then(function(authData) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase, create "users" data profile.
    setUserProfile(provider, authData, _timeStamp, _timeStamp);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // fall-back to browser redirects, and pick up the session
    // automatically when we come back to the origin page
    if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
      return fbAuth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(provider).then(function(authData) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase, create "users" data profile.
        setUserProfile(provider, authData, _timeStamp, _timeStamp);
      }).then(function() {
        // Never called because of page redirect
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // bad stuff happened :(
        showError(error);
      });
    } else {
      // bad stuff happened :(
      showError(error);
    }
  });
}

function setUserProfile(provider, authData, updatedAt, lastLoggedInAt) {
  switch (provider) {
    case "google":
      return createUserProfile(googleUserObject(authData, updatedAt, lastLoggedInAt), authData);
    case "twitter":
      return createUserProfile(twitterUserObject(authData, updatedAt, lastLoggedInAt), authData);
    case "facebook":
      return createUserProfile(facebookUserObject(authData, updatedAt, lastLoggedInAt), authData);
  }
}

function createUserProfile(userObject, authData) {
  var ref = fbUtilities.ref("users", authData.authGroup);
  ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var existsAuthGroup = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    if (!existsAuthGroup) {
      fbUtilities.handler(function(cb) {
        authData = ref.set(userObject, cb);
      });
    }
  });
}

function facebookUserObject(user, updatedAt, lastLoggedInAt) {
  return {
    key: user.uid,
    provider: user.provider,
    token: user.token,
    auth: user.auth,
    expires: user.expires,
    facebook: user.facebook,
    facebookId: user.facebook.id,
    accessToken: user.facebook.accessToken,
    name: user.facebook.displayName,
    email: user.facebook.email,
    picture: user.facebook.profileImageURL,
    cachedUserProfile: user.facebook.cachedUserProfile,
    createdAt: _timeStamp,
    updatedAt: updatedAt,
    lastLoggedInAt: lastLoggedInAt
  };
}
```

**socialLogin() Params:**

```
@provider = facebook, twitter, or google.

@options = "public_profile, user_friends, email" (if @provider === facebook)
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a scope (what you have in `@options`) that will return a better profile picture. You *can* however use the `authData` to query the Facebook graph API and get anything that's available there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796143/using-firebase-facebook-auth-with-facebook-graph-api

Comment: Hi Frank! Thanks for the comment. I agree with you, I had thought of that, but wasn't sure I wanted to make 2 outbound calls each time a user signs into the app. This very well might have to be my solution though. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. I'll mark this question as a duplicate then.