# Facebook API call with Firebase login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, firebase, angularfire

I have login tied to Facebook authentication, and this is all handled by Firebase.
However I need to make an API call to Facebook `'me/friends/'`
Since I am already logged in, how would I use OAuth object to make a call without making another request.

I am using following wrapper for Angular for connection to Facebook.
https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

Comment: You can find the Facebook token in `authData.accessToken`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688613/firebase-facebook-front-end-front-end-query/16697338#comment24081501_16697338

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need a wrapper.** `$firebaseAuth()` + `$http()` = easy Graph API requests.

The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5) is pretty easy to use and will work easily with Firebase.

Make sure you have the Facebook Friends permission enabled or you won't get any data back.

You can use `$firebaseAuth()` to login and get the Facebook `access_token`. That token can be used against the Graph API to get data via HTTP requests. Angular has a good `$http` library for making these calls.

Don't mind the way I structure the code, I prefer to use the [Angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', 'https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/')
  .constant('FacebookAppId', '<app-id>')
  .service('RootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .factory('Auth', Auth)
  .factory('Friends', Friends)
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function Friends($http, RootRef, $q, FacebookAppId) {

  function getFriends() {
    // get the currently logged in user (may be null)
    var user = RootRef.getAuth();
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var token = null;
    var endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="

    // if there is no logged in user, call reject 
    // with the error and return the promise
    if (!user) {
      deferred.reject('error');
      return deferred.promise;
    } else {
      // There is a user, get the token
      token = user.facebook.accessToken;
      // append the token onto the endpoint
      endpoint = endpoint + token;
    }

    // Make the http call
    $http.get(endpoint)
      .then(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
      });

    // return the promise
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    get: getFriends
  };
}
Friends.$inject = ['$http', 'RootRef', '$q', 'FacebookAppId'];

function Auth($firebaseAuth, RootRef) {
  return $firebaseAuth(RootRef);
}
Auth.$inject = ['FirebaseAuth', 'RootRef'];

function MainCtrl($scope, Friends) {

  $scope.login = function login() {
    Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook').then(function(authData) {
      console.log(authData, 'logged in!');
    });
  };

  $scope.getFriends = function getFriends() {
    Friends.get()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.data);
      });
  };

}
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Friends'];
```

Comment: Maybe this is outdated. Currently `getAuth()` does not return `user.facebook` property. I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @matheusrufca, I guess now (10/2016) you'd use `firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData`. See the `auth` [doc page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Comment: @AlanP I was looking for the fb access token stored on user. Currently it seems the only way to get fb acess token is on `$signInWithPopup` method callback. `$getAuth` and `$onAuth` does not provide Facebook data.